# C# Windows Forms не срабатывает событие нажатия клавиатуры

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, клавиатура

Добавил в проекте событие keyUp к форме(через конструктор формы). Событие не срабатывает, т.е. вообще не срабатывает, ставил точку останова, и при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры я туда не попадаю.
Сделал обработчики для других событий клавиатуры, тоже не работают в этом проекте. Другие события(например нажатие мыши) работают. 
Пробовал создавать новый проект в нём все события работают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я мог такого натворить у себя в проекте, что события клавиатуры перестали работать?
Можно ли это как то вылечить, или нужно создавать новый проект и туда всё перекидывать? Последнее делать не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

События `KeyDown` и `KeyUp` отправляются сфокусированному контролу. Если на форме есть другие контролы, и они сфокусированы, то они будут заглатывать эти события, и форме ничего не останется.

Если вы хотите, чтобы форме всегда приходили эти события, то установите для формы `KeyPreview=true`.

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо. А я уж испугался, что чего то не то сделал.